# Modify pandas dataframe from a function

Tags: python, pandas, function, dataframe

I find myself trying to modify several dataframes with the same operations again and again. I would like to put all modifications in a function and just call the function with the dataframe name and have all transformations done.

This is the code and all transformations I try to apply for now. When I run it, nothing happens, and the dataframe remains raw.

```
#create a preprocessing formula so the process can be applied to any dataset (traning and validation and competition)
def preprocessing(df):
    #inspect dataframe
    df.head()

    #check data types in dataframe
    np.unique(df.dtypes).tolist()

    #inspect shape before removing duplicates
    df.shape

    #drop duplicates
    df = df.drop_duplicates()

    #inspect shape again to see change
    df.shape

    #calculate rows that have a mean of 100 to remove them later
    mean100_rows = [i for i in range(len(df)) if df.iloc[i,0:520].values.mean() == 100 ]

    #calculate columns that have a mean of 100 to remove them later
    mean100_cols = [i for i in np.arange(0,520,1) if df.iloc[:,i].values.mean() == 100 ]

    #calculate columns labels that have a mean of 100 to remove them later
    col_labels = [df.columns[i] for i in mean100_cols]

    #delete rows with mean 100
    df.drop(index = mean100_rows, axis=0, inplace=True)

    #delete columns with mean 100
    df.drop(columns=col_labels, axis=1, inplace=True)

    #export columns that have been removed
    pd.Series(col_labels).to_csv('remove_cols.csv')

    #head
    df.head()

    #check size again
    df.shape
```

Comment: At the end `return df`, then do `df = preprocessing(df)`. DataFrames are `mutable` so you can modify them within a function without returning anything. However, I don't recommend that and many pandas operations return new objects so that will fail.

Comment: @ALollz Thank you so much, this works wonders!

Comment: You're also going to need to add `print()` around the lines like `df.shape` or else you won't see the output. If you're not printing those lines, they aren't doing anything and can be removed.

Answer (score 2):

In Python objects passed to functions by reference.

When the following line is executed

```
df = df.drop_duplicates()
```

You basically assign new reference to function parameter, but the object outside the function does not change.

I would suggest to change the function so it would return the df object and then assign it's return value to df object outside the function.